# I want to combine my www and non www and keep the link jucie from both

Tags: seo

My website shows up for some keywords in the www and some in the non www. Seaquake shows more links to the non www version. It is a PR2 either way. I would like to combine the link juice of the two versions into the non www version. Does anyone know the best way to combine the two and keep the link juice of both. It is as simple as a 301 redirect and if so does the 301 need to be handled in any specific way.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you choose the one you want (without www.) and you
301 redirect the other to the one you choose. (Using an htaccess directive to always remove the www. part for instance).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use the rel canonical tag in your website.  Check out this from the google webmaster tools:
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html

Answer (score 0):

The preferred domain is the one that you would liked used to index your site's pages. Links may point to your site using both the www and non-www versions of the URL.

For Instance:
http://www.example.com and http://example.com

The preferred domain is the version that you want used for your site in the search results.
Visit Google Web Master Tools for information on Canonical domain and what to prefer.